# String parameter handling in a Powershell function

Tags: powershell

Have just dipped my toes (fingers!) in to PowerShell recently for so Backup Exec and was looking to simplify my script by introducing a function to setup backup jobs, so I have started off with:

```
function submitJob ($beDef,$beTask,$beTape,$beCMD,$beDup)
{
$beCmdLine="GET-BEBackupDefinition ""$beDef"" "
}
```

I then call the function with

```
submitJob "SS03ICT","Wednesday (01)","Tape drive 0002 LTO3","powershell SS03-Media Wednesday",$true
```

and the result in beCmdLine is

```
GET-BackupDefinition "SS03ICT Wednesday (01) Tape drive 0002 LTO3 powershell SS03-Media Wednesday True"
```

I can see all the parameters contain the correct values individually but when I use just the first param ($beDef) it expands to include all the values. I just want to command to command to start as

```
GET-BackupDefinition "SS03ICT"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all too many quotes:

```
function submitJob ($beDef,$beTask,$beTape,$beCMD,$beDup)
{
   $beCmdLine="GET-BEBackupDefinition $beDef"
}
```

Then, you should call your function with space separated parameters, like this:

```
submitJob "SS03ICT" "Wednesday (01)" "Tape drive 0002 LTO3" "powershell SS03-Media Wednesday" $true
```

Comment: The quotes where fine - but it was the comma separation of the parameters that caused the issue - thanks.